# ParallelOptions with MaxDegreeOfParallelism and actual number of threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, parallel-processing, console-application

Hello I am doing "dynamic" multithreading with different values of `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` method but whenever I am trying to change value of `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` that's greater than 1 it's showing in console that program use more threads than I assigned.

```
public static string DoMultipleTasks(int threads, List<string> inputList)
{            
    ParallelOptions po = new ParallelOptions();          
    po.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = threads;
    Parallel.ForEach(inputList, po,  values =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" Name: {0}, Thread Id= {1}", values, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    });            
    return null;
}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MaxDegreeOfParallelism` specifies how many threads (or rather, tasks) can run at the same time. It doesn't specify which threads that should be.

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism?view=netcore-3.1):

> Gets or sets the maximum number of concurrent tasks enabled by this ParallelOptions instance.

During your execution of `Parallel.ForEach` you may run on many different threads (and therefore involve many different thread id's). That depends on the underlying thread scheduler.

You are, however, guaranteed that your block of code will at most have `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` executions at the same time.

While you basically have an example already, here is a slightly modified version of your code to show what I mean.

```
var dict = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, string>();
var po = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3 };
int count = 0, maxval = 0;
Parallel.ForEach(Enumerable.Range(1, 10000000), po, (d) =>
{
    Interlocked.Increment(ref count);
    dict.AddOrUpdate(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, "", (id, old) => old);

    lock (dict)
    {
        maxval = Math.Max(maxval, count);
    }
    Interlocked.Decrement(ref count);
});

Console.WriteLine("Count: " + count);
Console.WriteLine("Max: " + maxval);
Console.WriteLine("Thread ids: " + String.Join(", ", dict.Select(d => d.Key)));
```

It should result in an output similar to this:

> Count: 0
> Max: 3
> Thread ids: 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9

No matter how many times you run this code, the max value should never go above 3. On the other hand, the thread ids will change often.

Comment: Not sure about the downvote. Let me know if anything is unclear. :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and it wasn't my downvote. Everything is now clear but I am still confused why program runs slower on multithreading than on 1 thread.

Comment: Multithreading is not always the answer when you want to speed up the execution of your code. 
In your example you call `Console.WriteLine` which has to synchronize writes to the console, to not produce a garbled result. So even though you use multiple threads, they all end up waiting for each other anyway. So you have added more overhead (the thread management) just to print messages synchronously anyway.

Comment: Generally, if you need a lot of I/O operations, multithreading should not be your first go to. If you, on the other hand, needed to do a lot of CPU heavy work on each value in the collection (and that's where the time was spent), threading might be a good candidate to speed it up.

Comment: Upvoted. But using three different synchronization mechanisms in a small block of code is probably a bit too match (concurrent collection + `lock` + `Interlocked`). And still it's not thread-safe. In the line `maxval = Math.Max(maxval, count);` you should use the local `count` returned by the previous `Interlocked` invocation, instead of accessing the actively mutated shared value.